# How can I simplify the compilation process when compiling C files which use functions defined in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, avr-gcc

I am currently running a script to compile all .c and .s files to object code, and then linking. Is there a way to have an include statement in the C file to notify the compiler to also compile the appropriate assembly file? #include “somefile.s” does not work as GCC will attempt to process the included file as C.

Comment: No. That's what makefiles are for.

Comment: Assembly files aren't compiled. The compiler won't ever see them. `cc` is the compiler frontend; when it sees a `.s` file, it goes directly to the assembler without ever seeing the compiler. Thus, what you want doesn't really make a lot of sense. Learn how to write Makefiles instead.

Comment: Hopefully you are not `#include`-ing the C files either, so why do you expect that to work for assembly? For simple projects `gcc -o program *.c *.s` might work though.

Comment: for well structured simple-medium projects a makefile with implicit rules will work too, so you write + tune it once, and then it works even for new files, but it requires some basic understanding of `make` (and quite some docs reading while creating the one universal). There're also IDEs which are capable to help with setting up either classic makefile or CMake, those usually explicitly list all project files, which has its own pros/cons. Or even the IDE may have completely its own build system not using make at all, like U++ IDE. But in your case as you already have script, why not Makefile?

Comment: @fuz sorry for the lack of specificity in the question. Using AVR-GCC tool chain, I am compiling a .c file which contains main and assembling assembly files which contain functions called by main. I am then linking the object files and then generating intel hex files for flashing to a microcontroller. I wrote a shell script to handle the three separate commands but typing out every file name as the scripts arguments is getting cumbersome as the project grows. The script works well for testing a few modules, but I was interested in finding a better way. I will build a makefile, thanks!

Comment: @Alex Makefiles are that better way you are looking for.

Comment: the `make` script language has wildcard capabilities to automatically generate a macro that contains all the file names that match a pattern.  The most useful patterns are `*.c` and `*.h`  and You might find `*.s` very useful.  if your project is well organized, then you would use Makefile statements similar to: `SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)`   which would produce the appropriate macros where each macro contains a space separated list of: the sources files, the object files, the dependency files and the related header files respectively